# Derivative of block matrix using einstein notation

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, tensors, block-matrices, index-notation

Let $Y = [A \quad XB \quad C]$, where $A,B,C,X$ are all matrices with appropriate size. What is the derivative of $Y$ w.r.t. $X$?

The part that confuses me is that $\frac{\partial A}{\partial X}$ should be a zero 4-rank tensor. At the same time, $\frac{\partial X^{ij}B^{jk}} {\partial X^{lm}} = \frac{X^{ij}}{X^{lm}}B^{jk} = \delta_{il} \delta_{jm} B^{jk}$ should be a 3-rank tensor. It seems that the size of these tensors do not match.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't you have 4 variable indices in last expression $i,k,l,m$? I don't really get what you are asking though

Comment: If $A, B, C, X$ are matrices , then if we represent them as type (1,1) 2nd order tensors $Y$ must be a type (1,2) third order tensor. So if we write ${{A}^j}_i$, ${{B}^j}_i$, ${{C}^j}_i$, ${{X}^j}_i$ then ${{Y^j}_i}_k$ is a type (1,2) 3rd order tensor (and for example ${{Y^j}_i}_1={A^j}_i$). So $\partial Y/\partial X$ has to be a type (2,3) 5th order tensor.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\e{{\large\epsilon}}  \def\ve{{\large\varepsilon}}
\def\Eij{E_{ij}}
\def\Xij{X_{ij}}
\def\Ykl{Y_{k\ell}}
\def\Bjl{B_{jp}}
\def\Dki{\delta_{ki}}
\def\smA{{\small A}}
\def\smC{{\small C}}
\def\smF{{\small F}}
\def\smG{{\small G}}
\def\smH{{\small H}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\mc#1{\left[\begin{array}{c|c}#1\end{array}\right]}
$Given the matrix
$$\eqalign{
Y &= \mc{
A & XB & C \\
} \\
}$$
The gradient of $Y$ with respect to a single *scalar* element
of $X$ is
$$\eqalign{
\grad Y\Xij &= \mc{
0_\smA & \Eij\,B & 0_\smC \\
} \\
}$$
$\Eij$ is a matrix whose components are all $0$ except for
the $(i,j)$ element which equals $1$.

It is the component-wise $\:$ self-gradient of $X$
$$\eqalign{
\Eij = \grad X\Xij \\
}$$
The notation $0_\smA$ is meant to denote a zero matrix the same size as the matrix $A,\,$ i.e.
$$\eqalign{
 &0_\smA = A-A \\
 &0_\smC = C-C \\
}$$
Assume that $Y\in\bbR{m\times n}$ and the cartesian basis vectors for the two dimensions are $\e_k\in\bbR{m}$ and $\ve_\ell\in\bbR{n}$, then you can calculate the component-wise gradients as
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\Ykl}{\Xij}
 &= \e_k^T \mc{
0_\smA & \Eij\,B & 0_\smC \\
}\,\ve_\ell \\
}$$
Most of these scalar gradients will evaluate to zero, but for some **restricted range** of the index
$\LR{\,\ell_\smA < \ell < \ell_\smC}$ the non-zero gradients are given by
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\Ykl}{\Xij} &= \Dki\,\Bjl\qquad \LR{\,p\,=\,\ell-\ell_\smA} \\
}$$
Note that the presence of the Kronecker delta symbol means that most of the terms in this formula will also evaluate to zero.

Comment: How about the derivative of a scalar element of Y w.r.t a scalar element of X? It seems like you had something earlier but edited it out.

Comment: @nku  I don't know how helpful it will be, but I added it back to the post.

Comment: Fixed an indexing error on the $B$ matrix.

Comment: Interesting, so the expression for gradient for the non-zero part is different from what I wrote in the original question. Do you have any reference for this?